# Writing to an HDF5 file in parallel using chunking in fortran

Tags: arrays, parallel-processing, fortran, mpi, hdf5

**Problem**:  I have pieces of a 2D array scattered across multiple processors.  Imagine there is an array defined as

```
DOUBLE PRECISION :: F_TOTAL(n1:n2,m1:m2)
```

Now each processors has an array

```
DOUBLE PRECISION :: F(n1:n2,mystart:myend)
```

In the end I want to have `F_TOTAL` stored in an HDF5 file.

**Solution**:  This appears to be a good place to use Hyperslabs.  However the caveate is that while all processors have the same `n1` and `n2` `mystart` and `myend` are different.  Specifically the second dimension of each processors `F` is unique (but always >0).

**My Crashing Code**

```
  SUBROUTINE write_parhdf5(n1,n2,m1,m2,mystart,myend,Farr,var_name,comm)

  USE mpi_params
  USE hdf5

  IMPLICIT NONE
  INTEGER :: n1,n2,m1,m2,mystart,myend,comm
  DOUBLE PRECISION :: Farr(n1:n2,mystart:myend)
  CHARACTER(LEN=*), INTENT(in)  :: var_name

  INCLUDE 'mpif.h'

  INTEGER :: ier, info, rank
  INTEGER(HID_T) :: file_id, fspace_id, dset_id, mspace_id, &
                    fapl_id, dcpl_id, dxpl_id, driver_id
  INTEGER(HSIZE_T), ALLOCATABLE :: dimsf(:), counts(:), chunk_dims(:),&
                                   offset(:)

  !-------Begin Subroutine
  ier = 0
  info = MPI_INFO_NULL

  ! Initialize
  CALL h5open_f(ier)

  ! Setup File access
  CALL h5pcreate_f(H5P_FILE_ACCESS_F, fapl_id, ier)
  CALL h5pset_fapl_mpio_f(fapl_id, comm, info, ier)
  CALL h5pget_driver_f(fapl_id, driver_id, ier)
  ! Open file
  CALL h5fopen_f('file.h5', H5F_ACC_RDWR_F, file_id, ier, access_prp = fapl_id)

  ! Setup Helper Arrays
  rank =2;
  ALLOCATE(dimsf(rank),chunk_dims(rank),counts(rank),offset(rank))
  dimsf(1) = n2-n1+1
  dimsf(2) = m2-m1+1
  chunk_dims(1) = SIZE(Farr,1)
  chunk_dims(2) = SIZE(Farr,2)
  counts(1) = 1
  counts(2) = 1
  offset(1) = 0
  offset(2) = mystart-1

  ! Create Spaces
  CALL h5screate_simple_f(rank, dimsf, fspace_id, ier)
  CALL h5screate_simple_f(rank, dimsf, mspace_id, ier)

  ! Enable Chunking
  CALL h5pcreate_f(H5P_DATASET_CREATE_F, dcpl_id, ier)
  CALL h5pset_chunk_f(dcpl_id, rank, chunk_dims, ier)

  ! Create Dataset
  CALL h5dcreate_f(file_id, TRIM(var_name), H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE, fspace_id, dset_id, ier, dcpl_id)


  ! Select Hyperslab in memory
  CALL h5sselect_hyperslab_f(mspace_id, H5S_SELECT_SET_F, offset, chunk_dims, ier)

  ! Select Hyperslab in File
  CALL h5sselect_hyperslab_f(fspace_id, H5S_SELECT_SET_F, offset, chunk_dims, ier)

  ! Create Properties
  CALL h5pcreate_f(H5P_DATASET_XFER_F, dxpl_id, ier)
  CALL h5pset_dxpl_mpio_f(dxpl_id, H5FD_MPIO_COLLECTIVE_F, ier)


  ! Write dataset
  CALL h5dwrite_f(dset_id, H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE, Farr, dimsf, ier, mem_space_id = mspace_id, file_space_id = fspace_id, xfer_prp = dxpl_id)

  ! Close Property list
  CALL h5pclose_f(fapl_id, ier)
  CALL h5pclose_f(dcpl_id, ier)
  CALL h5pclose_f(dxpl_id, ier)
  CALL h5sclose_f(mspace_id, ier)
  CALL h5sclose_f(fspace_id, ier)
  CALL h5dclose_f(dset_id, ier)

  ! Deallocate Helpers
  DEALLOCATE(dimsf,chunk_dims,counts,offset)

  ! Close the file
  CALL h5fclose_f(file_id, ier)
  ! Close the fortran interface
  CALL h5close_f(ier)
  RETURN

  END SUBROUTINE write_parhdf5
```

The problem I get is that when I call this routine I get the error

```
 Error: Unsupported datatype passed to ADIOI_Count_contiguous_blocks, combiner = 17
```

It must be possible to have each processor write a different hyperslab size, right?

Comment: What MPI implementation are you using? It seems that the MPI-IO implementation is unable to handle the derived datatype constructed by the HDF5 library. This could happen with very old versions of ROMIO that ship with earlier versions of Open MPI - see [here](http://hdf-forum.184993.n3.nabble.com/unsupported-data-type-td4028431.html).

Comment: My current version of openmpi/1.4.3.  Maybe a better question would be this then:  If I use serial HDF5 can I have each processor independently write it's chunk to the file?  I would have the master process write it's chunk and then in sequence have each processor open the file and write it's chunk?

Comment: It is possible to have different sizes on different cpus. You must be aware that if you want to achieve collective I/O it is important to design your selection according to the hints here: https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/PHDF5/parallelhdf5hints.pdf The error you see is probably related to the system configuration as @HristoIliev mentioned. Either it is a managed system and you should see with the admin or it is yours and you could provide more details if you want help about this.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yes I believe it's an issue with the version of openmpi we're using.  I have a request in to get the list of libraries I need built with GCC 6 and the latest version of OpenMPI.  In the meantime, I modified my code to have each processors write it's chunk of the data to the file after the master processor write's it initially.  Again not a scalable solution (works fine for 100 processors but for 1000 it'll be slow).